# Use POS tags in typed dependencies with Stanford Parser

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have a set of sentences. For each of them I want to obtain a "generalized" typed dependencies graph in which every word is replaced by the corresponding POS tag (except verbs and some keywords like *LOCATION* and *TARGET*).

For example, from the sentence

```
take a left turn till you come to a LOCATION
```

I want to obtain

```
amod(take,JJ)dobj(take,NN)mark(come,IN)nsubj(come,PP)prep_to(come,LOCATION)
```

What is the simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved this problem with a bit of tree manipulation.

```
public static void exploreTree(Tree t) {
    List<Tree> child = t.getChildrenAsList();
    Tree terminal;
    for (Tree c : child) {
        if (c.isPreTerminal()) {
            terminal = c.getChild(0);
            String t_value = terminal.value();
            String c_value = c.value();
            if (!c_value.startsWith("VB")) {
                if (!t_value.equals("LOCATION") && !t_value.equals("TARGET")) {
                    terminal.setValue(c.value());
                }
            }
            // test[1].setValue(test[0].value());
        } else
            exploreTree(c);
    }
}
```

It change internal data of Stanford Parser tree according my request. Maybe is not the most elegant and robust solution but works.